# Would like to have more presentable table

Tags: tables

Want to have my table enough spaces between them and words that spill over are handled. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
    \caption{Selected Ebola Epidemic Compartmental Models, Analyses and Problem Formulations with References}
    \small
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \renewcommand\tabcolsep{0.75pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{lll>{\raggedright}Xlc}
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      \specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em}
      \textbf{Compartmental} & \textbf{Analysis} & \textbf{Problem} & \centering
      \textbf{Objective} & \textbf{Control Intervention} & \textbf{Reference}  \\
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      \textbf{Model} & & \textbf{Formulation} & & & \\
      \specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
      SEIT & Sensitivity & Differential & \mbox{}\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep-\partopsep\relax}%
      \begin{itemize} \setlength{\itemsep}{-5pt}
        \item Evaluate various intervention strategies
        \item Determine model parameters by least square method
      \end{itemize} & Vaccination & Sideman et al [1] \\ [-2ex] %
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't provide `\usepackage` statements for the `rotating`, `caption`, `threeparttable`, `natbib`, `xcolor`, and `colortbl` packages? What is to be gained by making potential answer writer wade through your code and figure out by trial and error which packages need to be loaded?

Comment: Please, fix the obvious errors, like missing packages (see Mico's comment), class name in curly braces, properly nested environments, no `table` inside `sidewaystable`, ...

Comment: This still can't possibly compile for you without error: the `sidewaystable` environment is never closed. You need to test your code before posting the example to make sure it compiles as is. Not to mention all the other problems. Why make it difficult to help you?

Comment: I've altered your code to make it compilable. I've adapted the first line to correct the syntax of `\documentclass`, added required packages and changed `mediumcyan` to `cyan` throughout. However, I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with the table....

Comment: I want some spaces between compartmental model and analysis. I also want all of my first row of text to be on the same line and straight. Finally words that spill over to the next line do not look well

Answer (score 2):

Don't reduce the separation between columns if you want reasonable spaces between them. You can use `enumitem` and a `minipage` to align the itemised environment with the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,enumitem,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
    \caption{Selected Ebola Epidemic Compartmental Models, Analyses and Problem Formulations with References}
    \small
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{lll>{\RaggedRight}Xlc}
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      \specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em}
      \textbf{Compartmental} & \textbf{Analysis} & \textbf{Problem} & \centering
      \textbf{Objective} & \textbf{Control Intervention} & \textbf{Reference}  \\
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      \textbf{Model} & & \textbf{Formulation} & & & \\
      \specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
      SEIT & Sensitivity & Differential &
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight
        \begin{itemize}[nosep]
          \item Evaluate various intervention strategies
          \item Determine model parameters by least square method
        \end{itemize}
      \end{minipage} & Vaccination & [1] \\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: adapted table]

Another possibility which may result in a more balanced presentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption,enumitem,ragged2e}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
    \caption{Selected Ebola Epidemic Compartmental Models, Analyses and Problem Formulations with References}
    \small
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{lll>{\RaggedRight}Xlc}
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      \specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em}
      \textbf{Compartmental} & \textbf{Analysis} & \textbf{Problem} & \centering
      \textbf{Objective} & \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Reference}  \\
      \rowcolor{cyan}
      \textbf{Model} & & \textbf{Formulation} & & \textbf{Intervention} & \\
      \specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em}
      SEIT & Sensitivity & Differential &
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight
        \begin{itemize}[nosep]
          \item Evaluate various intervention strategies
          \item Determine model parameters by least square method
        \end{itemize}
      \end{minipage} & Vaccination & [1] \\
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: better balance?]

Comment: Thanks but I want to ask one question. Can you please reduce the spaces between Evaluate various intervention strategies?

Comment: please make the contents of your minipages ragged right.

Comment: @user28251 You can use `\raggedright` before `\begin{itemize}` to make the contents flushed left rather than justified text, as barbara suggests. (I can't do this now - will try to remember later if I have time. But just put it before you start the `itemize` environment.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton OK ;).

Comment: @user28251 Please see edit. The first table now uses a ragged right setting (from `ragged2e`); the second does the same but also adjusts the penultimate column which may give better results. I think it is better here, but you'd obviously need to consider the effect on all rows in order to decide on the best layout.

Comment: i like the second version, but the headers should have "normal text" baseline separation, rather than the "row" separation of a table.  (okay, i'm a nitpicker.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree. But that is already covered in [Habi's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262173/) so I'm not sure it would be OK to do that as well. Plus, I'm not sure why the OP is doing it this way in the first place: personally, I wouldn't break the labels across rows. But, personally, I wouldn't colour the headers with a cyan background (or a `mediumcyan` background) either.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can also reformat your table a bit, to make it fit (nearly) on a line.
And in my opinion make it a bit nicer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Selected Ebola Epidemic Compartmental Models, Analyses and Problem Formulations with References}
    \small
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
        \begin{tabularx}{1.4\linewidth}{XlXXXl}
            \toprule
            Compartmental\newline Model & Analysis & Problem\newline Formulation & Objective & Control\newline Intervention & Reference \\
            \midrule
            SEIT    & Sensitivity   & Differential  & Evaluate various intervention strategies                      & Vaccination & [1] \\
                        &           &               & Determine model parameters by least square method &\\
        \end{tabularx}
    }
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of code above]